# Addthis - 2 different configurations on the same page

Tags: html, addthis

I would like to have 2 different configurations of addthis on the same page.

Take note that I'm using the new Addthis, where the code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" async="async"></script>
<div class="addthis addthisBlogue clearfix">
    <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is have 1 that have the share numbers tooltips [image] and the other doesn't [image]

Is it possible?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible just by using the dashboard configuration: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/9644893-on-same-page-post-to-dispaly-same-time-2-sharing-bars-toolboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since AddThis creates HTML elements that contain the count 'tooltip' (it's not actually a tooltip) with a single class or ID element, if you want to be really specific (i.e. choose what to hide exactly where you have two or more AddThis instances on a page) you could:

1. add the instance where you want to **hide** the count inside a div with a CSS ID or unique class;
2. use `display: none` to hide the *parent social media count element* **only** inside that div.

### Target the AddThis where you want to hide the count elements

Seems obvious, but For example, on [this page](http://basicblogtips.com/addthis-plugin.html) if you inspect (e.g. in Chrome) the rendered Facebook and Twitter AddThis elements and add 'display: none' to the `.pluginCountButton` and `.count-o` styles that contain the elements you want to hide, as expected: they vanish from the display.

**So** if you nest your AddThis instances **inside a uniquely-identified div** (or any parent element) then you could simply target the one you want to hide like this:

```
#hiddencount .pluginCountButton,
#hiddencount .count-o {
  display: none;
}
```

You'd need to locate the equivalent `.pluginCountButton` and `.count-o` elements for your version and instance—each social media icon has it's own so you'd have to identify each, as in the above example. You may also need more specificity between `#hiddencount` and the count container to get the style to apply.

NOTE: without a working example with the count links showing, this is untested. If you have a working example, I'd be happy to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Through some digging I discovered the answer.

You need to add the class addthis_toolbox to your divs like so:

```
<div class="addthis addthis_toolbox addthisBlogue clearfix">
    <div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
</div>
```

*source: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/5024966-multiple-share-button-on-same-page*